# TCP Connect With Invalid Connection Blocks Port

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I'm writing a TCP communication script in c++ to communicate between my computer and an Aldebaran Nao robot.

In general my script is working.  However, the trouble I am having is that when I call connect from the client (when the server application is closed or the ethernet connection removed) I get an error that the operation is in progress.

However, once the server application is restarted / ethernet cable reconnected, I still cannot call connect to successfully reestablish a connection.  I still get an error that the operation is in progress.

As a note, whenever my client determines that a connection cannot be made, the socket descriptor is closed before reattempting a connection.  Here is my code for connecting on the client side:

If there is any more information that would be useful, I would be happy to provide it.  This project is relatively large, so I didn't want to include too much irrelevant information here.

```
 TCPStream* TCPConnector::connect(const char* serverIP, int port, int timeoutSec)
{
    if (timeoutSec == 0)
    {
        return connect(serverIP, port);
    }

    struct sockaddr_in address;

    // Store all zeros for address struct.
    memset(&address, 0, sizeof(address));

    // Configure address struct.
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_port = htons(port); // Convert from host to TCP network byte order.
    inet_pton(PF_INET, serverIP, &(address.sin_addr)); // Convert IP address to network byte order.

    // Create a socket.  The socket signature is as follows: socket(int domain, int type, int protocol)
    int sd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    int optval = 1;

    if (setsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &optval, sizeof optval) == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "failed to set socket option" << std::endl;
    }

    // Set socket to be non-blocking.
    int arg;
    arg  = fcntl(sd, F_GETFL, NULL);
    arg |= O_NONBLOCK;
    fcntl(sd, F_SETFL, arg);

    // Connect with time limit.
    fd_set set;
    FD_ZERO(&set);    // Clear the set.
    FD_SET(sd, &set); // Add our file descriptor to the set.

    struct timeval timeout;
    timeout.tv_sec  = timeoutSec;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    // If the connect call returns 0, then the connection was established.  Otherwise,
    // check if the three-way handshake is underway.
    if (::connect(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address)) < 0)
    {
        // If the handshake is underway.
        if (errno == EINPROGRESS)
        {
            std::cout << "handshake in progress" << std::endl;

            // Designate timeout period.
            int ret = select(sd + 1, NULL, &set, NULL, &timeout);

            std::cout << "return value from select : " << ret << std::endl;

            // Check if timeout or an error occurred.
            if (ret <= 0)
            {
                return NULL;
            }
            else
            {
                // Check if select returned 1 due to an error.
                int valopt;
                socklen_t len = sizeof(int);

                getsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, (void*)(&valopt), &len);

                if (valopt)
                {
                    char * errorMessage = strerror( errno); // get string message from errn
                    std::string msg (errorMessage);
                    std::cout << msg << std::endl;


                    return NULL;
                }
            }  
        }
        else
        {
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    // Return socket to blocking mode
    arg = fcntl(sd, F_GETFL, NULL);
    arg &= (~O_NONBLOCK);
    fcntl(sd, F_SETFL, arg);

    // Create stream object.
    return new TCPStream(sd, &address);
}
```

Comment: It doesn't block the port. You code is going into an infinite loop.

Comment: @EJP Could you explain what is causing the infinite loop?

Answer (score 1):

Your socket is non-blocking mode (you do it explicitly).

As a result, your connect will return immediately with 'connection is in progress'. When socket is non-blocking, you would need than to `poll` on this socket and wait for it to become readable and/or writeable - this would mean connection is completed (either successfully or not).

A better option in my view would be to use blocking sockets - I see no reason for you to use non-blocking call here.

Comment: I incorporated non-blocking sockets so that my client application could proceed, even if a connection was not possible.  Right after setting the socket to be non-blocking, I use select to poll for a response over a given timeout period.

Comment: Right approach, assuming you aren't writing for Windows (use overlapped io)  but that won't help you with the connect. One way or another you'll have to wait for the connection to complete or fail like Sergey said. On the other hand, it looks like you're headed in [the same direction as boost::asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html). Probably worth your time looking into it before burning too much time reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @Austin, what's the point than? You are still waiting for connection result. Just do a blocking socket and save yourself a lot of worries.

Comment: @SergeyA Because I need to be able to return control to the calling application eventually.  Wouldn't a block indefinitely take control until a connection was established or an error occurred?

Comment: Also, do you guys think the timeout is the problem.  Usually the connection happens very quickly, so I'm not sure why in this one case it would take much longer to establish a connection.

Comment: @Austin, I am pretty sure this is what is happening.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a shot with blocking on and see what happens.